# MQL4 code to analyse charts

Tags: mql4

I'd like to write out an MQL4 EA that finds out pattern on charts without trading them.

A sort of exploration of the charts that outputs only a list of dates where the conditions I'm looking for are verified.

For example I try to find out all trends where the price moves in a range of 100 pips in less than 8 hours, but without opening any position, only storing all records in a list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible

just list all the conditions you desire to meet
and
test on all bars, whether all of these conditions were met.

```
if ( all_conditions_met == True ) { ReportThisJustFoundCandidate( aFileNAME ); }
```